# MSAL Web API Authorization has been denied for this request error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting message

```
{    "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request." }
```

when trying to use API from https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebAPI-DotNet as seen in the postman screenshot below:

[image]

I am trying to call it from js file

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: window.config.webApi + "TodoList/Get",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
}).done(function (data) {
    logMessage("Web APi returned:\n" + JSON.stringify(data));
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    logMessage("Error calling the Web api:\n" + textStatus);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your WebAPI controller code? Also post code of your Startup class of Web API

Comment: You need to check the access token in a service like jwt.io. Check that the audience claim matches your API.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the token in the figure, you were acquiring the **access_token** with Microsoft Account which is not able to be decoded.

AFAIK, in this scenario, to call the web API which protected by Azure AD V2.0 app, we can using the **id_token** which the appid is same as the app which you were using to protect the web API. And if you debug the code and capture the request using Fiddler, the code sample you mentioned also use the id_token to send the request for authorization.

Please feel free to let me know if it works for you.